# Javascript Abort POST Request on Retry/Refresh (HIGH CPU Usage)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, apache, cpu

Recently my Apache server's CPU has been at 100% (all day, that is). I think I have found my issue.

On a page, a user has the ability to click a button and send a POST request to a PHP file on my server. Sometimes the PHP file takes a LONG (and I mean VERY long) time to respond or sometimes does not respond at all:

```
function buttonFunction() {
    $.post("http://ipaddress/core/file.php",{username:username, password:pword, coins:coins}, function(data) {
        // Stuff
    });
}
```

**Hypothesis 1:**

I believe that sometimes people might click this button again (while  it is still trying to get the result/response from `file.php` from the previous click), and therefore causing two simultaneous processes from PHP on the Apache server - causing higher CPU usage (I *think* that's what happens, correct me if I'm wrong because I'm new to this server stuff).

**Hypothesis 2:**

Another thing that may be causing the high CPU usage (that I believe) is the user refreshing the page while it is still trying to get the result/response from `file.php`. After 12 seconds (with no response/result), I have a message appear saying "Please refresh if this takes too long." With that being the case (after refreshing the page), the user once again tries to send a post request to `file.php` while the old one may still be running - causing higher CPU usage (again, I *think* that's what happens, correct me if I'm wrong because I'm new to this server stuff).

**Reasoning:**

I'm saying this because on my site it may say that there are only 12 people online (and probably 12 people sending the post requests), however when I run the `top` command on PuTTY to see what processes are currently running, it shows nearly 30-40+ processes running (some taking as long as *17 minutes*).

So, is there a way that I can abort the request on a refresh (if it's still going on) or on the click on the button (again, if the request is still going on)? **In fact, can somebody either confirm or deny if my hypotheses (especially hypothesis 2) are correct - if those actually ARE causing the high CPU?** Furthermore, if anybody has an idea for a more efficient way that I can go about this (sending these requests), it would be highly appreciated.

**Edit 1:**

I can fix the possible issue stated in my first hypothesis. However, can somebody **please either confirm or deny** if my second hypothesis is true/valid?

Comment: `So, ... or on the click on the button...` Disable the button immediately after it is clicked.

Comment: @afaolek Yes, that was my first thought.

Comment: i would put as many locks around `file.php` so that only one request happens per whatever.

Comment: The file process is ABSOLUTELY still running when the page is refreshed to send a second request. There is no (reasonable) way of killing a PHP process on the server, when the client refreshes the script.

Comment: you can use db or client side storage to restrict user to request again when one request is in process

Comment: But doing as @ShovanSahu says will still require you to make the second request to see if the first one is open.

Comment: if it is client storage, it need not to make a server request

Comment: @ShovanSahu But if it's client side, the user can modify it to make more requests. The browser is always in the hands of the enemy.

Comment: correct this problem first: `Sometimes the PHP file takes a LONG (and I mean VERY long) time to respond or sometimes does not respond at all` BTW: why is this irregular?

Comment: I would agree with @LuisSiquot. The real problem here is with the PHP file, not with the UI handling or multiple requests.